# Split one column in Pandas dataframe by delimiter

Tags: pandas, dataframe

**My SQL Query (via pd.read_sql_query) returns dataset (df.to_csv output):**

```
BODY
"AAAA,BBBB,CCC"
"DDD,EEE,FFF"
...

[294 rows x 1 columns]
```

**And I need to split to 3 columns (delimited by comma).**

**Tried:**

- df.iloc[:,0].str.split(',', expand=True)
- df['BODY'].str.split(',',
  expand=True)

***In Python I am doing this with "datafile.writerows((col.split(",") for (col,) in result_set))" but don't know how with Pandas.***

Comment: can you provide `df.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code should work as it's described in the Pandas documentation.

Comment: Your code doesn't change the dataframe, though. Either of those lines only outputs three columns.

Comment: To save the split result to 3 new columns, you can write df[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']] = df['BODY'].str.split(',', expand=True)

Answer (score 0):

My mistake,

df = df.iloc[:,0].str.split(',', expand=True)

works.

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to delete your question.